# Javascript's Hash-Table Vs Variables

Tags: javascript, performance, hashtable, var

I'm kind new to JavaScript, studying it alone, and I thought about something to maybe improve my coding.

I can write code with 1000 vars.

But will it be smarter to have just 1 var which is a Hash-table.

Let's say I have:

```
var a = 5;
var b = new Date(); // just example
```

Will it be smarter to do:

```
var hash = new Object();
hash['a'] = 5;
hash['b'] = new Date();
```

Will my code load faster ? run faster ? save memory ?

Thanks.

Comment: how about an array? x[0], x[1] , ...

Comment: The difference is object orientation. It's nicer to work with objects rather than simple variables

Comment: (Mitch) but I want all types of objects, with different names..

Comment: It doesn't matter.  You should use whichever approach is more readable.

Comment: (Ashley) but I don't mean to use it for simple variables, I gave new Date() as an example. (or am I missing something ?)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: (Slaks + Ashley) so basically it will be the same but less readable ? (You'll have to read 'hash' 10000 times :) )

On second thought, I can use this like
read_only['a'] ..
editable['b'] ..

to mark what type of object I'm dealing with

Comment: Rule of thumb: if `5` and `new Date()` are logically related (e.g. properties of the same thing) then throw them in an object, if they're not related then leave them in separate variables. Of course, that's just a rule of thumb.

Comment: One way of putting it. Objects make complex programs a lot easier to maintain and write as well.

Comment: Thanks mu is too short and Ashley, have a great week :)

Answer (score 0):

You may find you can make your code more readable by grouping variables:

```
var hash;

hash = {

    a: 5,
    b: new Date(),

    // Add a nested object to group event handling functions, for example.
    handlers: {
        doClick: function () { ... },
        doSomething: function () { ... }
    }
};
```

As your code grows, you'll find it easier to keep track of things.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, local variables are generally faster to access than hash elements. Global variables, on the other had, are usually implemented as elements of the global object, so in that case there will be very little performance difference. Collecting variables together into logically coherent objects makes a lot of sense for ease of programming and for maintenance. (Note, however, that throwing a bunch of unrelated values into an object can create confusion, especially when you need to come back to your code weeks later and figure out what you were trying to do. So the "logically coherent" qualifier is, in my opinion, quite important.) It can also cut down on the number of parameters that need to be passed around to functions, which might improve performance a bit.

Comment: Hey, so the only good performance improvement you talked about is "sending less pointer to functions as parameters" ?
Instead of sending 10 parameters, you send 1 containing 10 'pointers' ?

Comment: @MikoDiko - That's the only _performance_ benefit I could think of. More important, I think, are the benefits that come from organizing data into conceptual groupings.